# color swatch that works with group products and configurable products

Tags: magento-1.7, configurable-product, grouped-products, simple-product

in my store there are two type of configurable products 'product-1' with attributes color,size and 'product-2' with attributes just color and these two configurable products are linked with grouped product so unfortunately Color swatch that i found from Google paid and free just works with configurable products so please share with me any color swatch extension which also works with grouped products

Comment: see this one, it works with all product types in Magento...http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/color-swatches-custom-product-options.html

Comment: no this just works with simple product i just now talk with their support Representative even amasty also not works with grouped

Comment: ok, i think the text mentions it works with all product types, or you can ask for customization